# How to solve ''API unavailable" problem while using recognition_google()

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I want to write a simple "Guess the Word" game with the SpeechRecognition package.But when I try to use recognition_google() to recognize the word, it always says "API unvailable" or "The remote host forced the closure of an existing connection".How can I solve the problem?

```
# adjust the recognizer sensitivity to ambient noise and record audio
# from the microphone
with microphone as source:
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = recognizer.listen(source, timeout=7)

# set up the response object
response = {
    "success": True,
    "error": None,
    "transcription": None
}

# try recognizing the speech in the recording
# if a RequestError or UnknownValueError exception is caught,
#     update the response object accordingly
try:
    response["transcription"] = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
except sr.RequestError:
    # API was unreachable or unresponsive
    response["success"] = False
    response["error"] = "API unavailable"
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    # speech was unintelligible
    response["error"] = "Unable to recognize speech"

return response
```

when I try to recognize the word,it will say "API unvailable" or "The remote host forced the closure of an existing connection".

Comment: Use paid version of the google API or any other speech recognition API.